# How to send a socket message from another module?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

My application is now structured according to "textbook" as follows:

File app.js:

```
var app = require("express").express();
var api = require("./routes/api"); //just an example of one route
app.use("/api",api);
...
var server = app.listen(8081);
var sockets = require("./routes/sockets")(server);
```

File routes/api.js:

```
var router = require("express").router;
route.get("/test", function(req,res) {
   res.render("test.pug");
}

router.get("/f", function(req, res) {
  //...some processing...
  //I want to send a socket message here to a given socket id !!!
  //
}
module.exports = router;
```

File routes/sockets.js:

```
module.exports = function (server) {
   var io - require("socket.io")(server);

   io.use("....

   io.on("connection",function(socket) {
     socket.on("....
     socket.on("....
   }
}
```

The above works fine for my web pages, eg `/api/test`, that talk directly to socket functions in sockets.js. What I need now is to be able to send a socket message to a specific socket id from inside api.js as shown at `!!!`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

**In one liner use**

```
io.to(socket_id).emit('msgtcln');
```

Full Example (combining 3 file into one).

```
"use strict";
var app = require("express")();

app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Sending Hello");
  io.to(id[0]).emit('msgtcln', {/* 3 */
    name:"Sending data"
  });

});

app.get("/f", function(req, res) {});

var server = app.listen(3000);


var io = require('socket.io')(server);

let id = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("Socket connected");
  id[0] = socket.id;
  socket.on('disconnect', function(opt, cb) {
    console.log("Socket disconnected");
  });
});
```

Here I am simply sending data through id array when /test route is hit, you have to maintain socket_id as per your need.

Comment: Thanks, but in the real world it is not practical to have everything in one file. My issue was how to expose the io `Server` object to other modules (files), specifically api.js. I worked out a roundabout method of doing it and it works. May post the answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Buried in the socket.io documentation is [sending mesagges from the outside world](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#sending-messages-from-the-outside-world), and the answer is [socket.io-emitter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-emitter).